# jquery accordion scrolls to top on activate, then breaks on second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a jquery accordion which scrolls to the top of the link that is clicked. The following code achieves this, but breaks when the link is clicked for a second time:

```
$(function () {
    $("#paper-types").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var scrollTop = $(".accordion").scrollTop();
            var top = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
            $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTop + top - 35
            }, "fast");
        }

   });
});
```

This can be seen on a jsfiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/6PPEZ/1/

What is broken in this code that stops it working on the second click?

EDIT: One thing that I have noticed is that it only stops working if you click the title to collapse the accordion. If you instead open the next link, the original link can be opened again without a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ui.newHeader` will be empty object in case of collapsing the accordion panel, that is throwing it off when you try to access top of undefined (offset() of empty jq object returns undefined). Just add a check `if(!ui.newHeader.length) return;`

```
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var scrollTop = $(".accordion").scrollTop();
        if(!ui.newHeader.length) return;
        var top = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTop + top - 35
        }, "fast");
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CR9n/)**

From [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)

> If the accordion is collapsing, ui.newHeader and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

Comment: Yo, howz it goin! I have put a small demo so the body doesn't scroll rest is cooleos + 1  **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jup5B/

Comment: Thanks PSL - this worked perfectly! Great explanation. Tats_innit I have kept the "html, body" as I am wanting the page to scroll to the top of the link. Thanks both for your input!

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/EU9LE/

I have changed things which were not needed,

- instead of `$("html,body")` use this
- Also instead of `offset` use the `$(ui.newHeader).top`;

This will fit the need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    $("#paper-types").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var scrollTop = $(".accordion").scrollTop();
            var top = $(ui.newHeader).top;
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTop + top - 35
            }, "fast");
        }

   });
});
```